# OpenOffice how to add more than 3 conditional formatting?

Tags: openoffice-basic

How to add more than 3 conditional formatting in OpenOffice ?

By defaut it's 3, but i want add more, how can I do it ?

For this moment I have 3, like this:

```
$H21="OPEN"

$H21="CLOSED"

$H21="SEND
```

But a want to add another 2 conditions like:

```
$H21="WAITING"

$H21="DELETED"
```

Thanks

Comment: If this hasn't been asked there already, I'd suggest deleting this question and asking it over on [su], though consider adding more details in order to clarify the question more precisely (if necessary).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade to LibreOffice, which allows an unlimited number.  Here is the dialog for AOO:

[image: only 3 conditions]

And here is the dialog for LO:

[image: unlimited conditions]

If sticking with OpenOffice is a requirement, then you could write a macro.  See the question [here](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?t=38922), which shows a macro for 4 conditions.